# Como o ".include?" no Ruby foi desenvolvido?

Tags: ruby

Estava tentando verificar se uma letra está inclusa num array sem usar o *.include?* mas não consigo o mesmo resultado. Alguém tem ideia de como funciona o *.include?* por "dentro"?

O código em questão é uma espécie de jogo da forca. O jogador chuta uma letra, a letra é incluída num *array* que é mostrado a cada chute a fim de informar os chutes efetuados. Se o jogador chutar uma letra que já foi chutada, o jogo deve informar que já foi feito o chute e pedir um novo chute.Tem um laço `while` que repete a solicitação de chutes enquanto o jogador não errar 5 vezes.

```
chutes_ate_agora = ["a","b","c","d"] #chutes hipotéticos
novo_chute = gets.strip

for chute in chutes_ate_agora
    if chute == novo_chute
       puts "já chutou letra #{novo_chute}"
       next  #vai para o loop while para pedir um novo chute
    else
       chutes_ate_agora << novo_chute
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem o [código fonte dele](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/49029811d998d919c1f31f39e7a4b82f42ff3eaa/array.c#L5305). Como eu pude ver é o mais óbvio possível, ele percorre todo o *array* com um laço e filtra se cada elemento é igual ou não ao que se está procurando. Assim que achar o primeiro já pode encerrar.

```
VALUE
rb_ary_includes(VALUE ary, VALUE item)
{
    long i;
    VALUE e;

    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
    e = RARRAY_AREF(ary, i);
    if (rb_equal(e, item)) {
        return Qtrue;
    }
    }
    return Qfalse;
}
```

Com a edição o código correto seria este:

```
def includes(array, valor)
    for item in array
        if item == valor
           return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

chutes_ate_agora = ["a","b","c","d"]
novo_chute = gets.strip
teste = includes(chutes_ate_agora, novo_chute)
if teste then
   puts "já chutou letra #{novo_chute}"
else
   chutes_ate_agora << novo_chute
end
print chutes_ate_agora
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/02JIm7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ynanepfj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/AlternateInclude.rb)

Claro que só tem desvantagens fazer assim. Use o que tem pronto.

Comment: Para informar o problema específico, eu posso colocar o código aqui por comentário ou edito a pergunta?

Comment: Edita a pergunta, se ninguém mais responder antes.

Comment: edição feita, desculpe se não tiver sido da forma mais adequada, sou novo por aqui.

Comment: E qual é o objetivo? Me parece que está tudo ok.

Comment: O problema é que quando entro com um chute que já foi feito, ele avisa que já foi feito, mas ainda assim armazena o chute repetido no array de chutes, o que só deveria acontecer se fosse um chute que não foi feito.

Comment: Tem algum motivo para não usar o `include`?

Comment: Apenas para ver se consigo o mesmo resultado sem esse "facilitador".

Comment: De toda forma, a pergunta foi respondida, muito obrigado!!

Comment: Consegue o mesmo se fizer certo. Eu postei, mas não faz sentido.